# Go template and function

Tags: go, go-templates

In my go code I often use `if` like this

```
if user && user.Registered { }
```

equivalent code in go templates would be

```
{{ if and .User .User.Registered }} {{ end }}
```

Unfortunately code in the template fails, if `.User` is `nil` :/

Is it possible to achieve the same thing in go templates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The template `and` function does not do [short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation like the Go `&&` operator.

The arguments to the `and` function are evaluated before the function is called. The expression `.User.Registered` is always evaluated, even if `.User` is nil.

The fix is to use nested `if`:

```
 {{if .User}}{{if .User.Registered}}  {{end}}{{end}}
```

You can avoid the nested `if` or `with` by using a template function:

```
func isRegistered(u *user) bool {
  return u != nil && u.Registered
}

const tmpl = `{{if isRegistered .User}}registered{{else}}not registered{{end}}`

t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"isRegistered": isRegistered}).Parse(tmpl))
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/0qBR9qBnOz)

Comment: I'm trying to escape using nested ifs ..because it would duplicate too much template code in between

Comment: even though this isn't the real solution i'm gonna accept it .

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the `{{with}}` action instead of the `and` template function.

Quoting from package doc of [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> ```
> {{with pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
>     If the value of the pipeline is empty, no output is generated;
>     otherwise, dot is set to the value of the pipeline and T1 is
>     executed.
> ```

Using `{{with}}` often results in cleaner and shorter code, as inside the `{{with}}` the dot `.` is already set to the non-empty "wrapper", the `.User` in our case; moreover you don't have to worry about how and if the arguments of the `and` template function are evaluated.

Your template rewritten:

```
{{with .User -}}
    {{if .Registered}}REGISTERED{{end}}
{{- end}}
```

Testing it without and with a user:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(tmpl))

fmt.Println("No user:")
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

u := struct{ Registered bool }{true}
fmt.Printf("User: %+v\n", u)
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]interface{}{"User": u}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F62nqRVpev)):

```
No user:
User: {Registered:true}
REGISTERED
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is the same as using nested ifs, which i'm trying not to use

Comment: @Goranek You did not mention that in your question.

Comment: sorry i thought it was obvious what i wanted to achieve :(