# How to have short circuit with and/or in text/template

Tags: go, go-templates

I have this Go template:

```
{{ if and $b.Trigger $b.Trigger.Name }} 
  Name is {{ $b.Trigger.Name }}.
{{ else }}
  ...other stuff...
{{ end }}
```

I'm trying to get this template to do:

```
if b.Trigger != nil && $b.Trigger.Name != "" { ...
```

however it doesn't work, because as [text/template godoc](https://godoc.org/text/template) says, both arguments to and/or functions are evaluated.

When the `$b.Trigger.Name` is evaluated, it errors out because `$b.Trigger` can be nil. So it returns error:

> `template: builds.html:24:46: executing "content" at <$b.Trigger.Name>: can't evaluate field Name in type *myType`

I tried refactoring this to:

```
{{ if and (ne $b.Trigger nil) (ne $b.Trigger.Name "") }}
```

and weird enough, this fails as well, it says I can't compare $b.Trigger with nil, which doesn't make sense because that field is a pointer type:

> `template: builds.html:24:31: executing "content" at <ne $b.Trigger nil>: error calling ne: invalid type for comparison`

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go template and function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208440/go-template-and-function).

Comment: By default `if` can handle `nil` values `{{ if $b.Trigger }}`, if its `non-nil` it will get in. Then you can add nested `if` for empty string check.

Comment: Or you can add your own template func please refer @icza comment.

Comment: Nest your ifs. Dead simple. readable and not clever.

Answer (score 5):

As Volker noted above, nest the ifs:

```
{{if $b.Trigger}}{{if $b.Trigger.Name}}
  Name is {{ $b.Trigger.Name }}.
{{end}}{{end}}
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
{{with $b.Trigger}}{{with .Name}}
  Name is {{.}}.
{{end}}{{end}}
```

Unfortunately, the above won't handle else clauses. Here's one (rather ugly) possibility:

```
{{$bTriggerName := ""}}
{{with $b.Trigger}}{{$bTriggerName = .Name}}{{end}}
{{with $bTriggerName}}
  Name is {{.}}.
{{else}}
  ...other stuff...
{{end}}
```

I looked to see if gobuffalo/plush could do this more elegantly, but as of 2019-04-30 it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Here explains why all arguments are evaluated in a pipeline.
It is evaluated through go template functions
https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions